# Linux change group permission to match owner permissions

Tags: linux, bash, permissions, filesystems, chmod

Suppose I have a directory on Linux with a bunch of files and subdirectories. This is that root directory:

```
drwxr-xr-x  13 user1 group1    4096 May  7 15:58 apps
```

Now, I only want to alter the group portion of those permissions. I want to alter it in such a way that it exactly matches the owner portion. The result for that directory would be:

```
drwxrwxr-x  13 user1 group1    4096 May  7 15:58 apps
```

But, I want a script or command to do this automatically, not just for that directory but for every subdirectory and file recursively under it. Anyone know how?

Thanks.

Comment: @Lucas -- No I didn't want to alter the ownership; just the permissions that were granted. See the responses if you still don't get it.

Answer (score 49, accepted):

Give this a try (test it first):

```
chmod -R g=u apps
```

The `=` copies the permissions when you specify a field (`u`, `g` or `o`) on the right side or sets it absolutely when you specify a permission (`r`, `w` or `x`) on the right.

Answer (score 4):

That's simple:

```
chmod g=u <file>
```